# I want to replace all commas between the 13th comma starting from left and 12th comma starting from right in Unix

Tags: unix

Present

```
1856292496,-1863203096,302,918468087151,808648712,405670043170066,919015026101,M,6,T,0,15,2c,Dear Customer, Your Request is under Process,03,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/,11/05/2017 10:00:00,0,03,,255,,333,ERecharge_RCOM,919015540301
```

Requirement

```
1856292496,-1863203096,302,918468087151,808648712,405670043170066,919015026101,M,6,T,0,15,2c,Dear Customer Your Request is under Process,03,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/,11/05/2017 10:00:00,0,03,,255,,333,ERecharge_RCOM,919015540301
```

Current

```
1856292499,-1863203087,301,918081224379,808648711,405540046666191,919026240102,M,6,T,0,15,8d,Dear Business Partner,your current Core balance is Rs.29.8,GSM balance is Rs.12892.14,MRCOM balance is Rs.1 and MRTL balance is Rs.1.Reliance,03,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/,11/05/2017 10:00:00,0,01,,255,,333,BalQuery_RCOM,919835853611
```

Requirement

```
1856292499,-1863203087,301,918081224379,808648711,405540046666191,919026240102,M,6,T,0,15,8d,Dear Business Partner your current Core balance is Rs.29.8 GSM balance is Rs.12892.14 MRCOM balance is Rs.1 and MRTL balance is Rs.1.Reliance,03,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/,11/05/2017 10:00:00,0,01,,255,,333,BalQuery_RCOM,919835853611
```

I need to replace all the commas between the 13th comma from the left to the 12th comma starting from the right with a space, on a Unix system.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  It helps to show [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  It also helps to know what tools you'll consider.  In this context, is Awk or Perl or Python an option?  You've correctly shown the input and required output data, with two well chosen examples.  The only possible complaint is that maybe '5th comma from left and 7th from the right' (or other smaller numbers than 13 and 12) would make it easier to handle.  But you should show what you've tried.

Comment: Actually I am a little new to unix and want to try it with awk but can't think of a way,

Comment: all I could come up with is this[root@PMS]# awk -F"," '{print $1 ","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7","$8","$9","$10","$11"$12"$13","$14}' CDR_2017051100.txt | more
1856252627,-1863282815,917827516705,302,825819144,405050035380268,919015000105,M,1,T,0$1218,*302*7428196597*69*7515#
1856252627,-1863282814,302,917827516705,808648712,405150035380268,919015000105,M,6,T,0$122c,Dear Customer

Comment: That should be edited into the question.  It doesn't combine the fields with spaces, or preserve the fields after the ones that should be combined.  Still, it is better than no code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a moderately succinct but mostly inscrutable (if not incomprehensible) solution using Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -anlF,
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lhs = 13;
my $rhs = 13;

$, = ",";     # Perl is obscure on occasion!
my($nflds) = scalar(@F);
print @F[0 .. $lhs-1], "@F[$lhs .. $nflds-$rhs-1]", @F[$nflds-$rhs .. $nflds-1]
    if ($nflds > $lhs + $rhs);
```

- The shebang line uses `-l` to make Perl handle newlines automatically.  See [`perldoc perlrun`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).
- It also uses `-F,` which, in Perl 5.20.0 and later, is explicitly documented to automatically put Perl into `-a` (`awk`) mode and `-n` (read loop but don't print) mode.  The input lines are automatically split into the array `F` using `,` as the delimiter.  Earlier versions of Perl do not infer `-a` and `-n` from the presence of `-F`, so the code (now) uses `-an` as well as `-F,`.  The updated code has been shown to work with Perl 5.10.0 and with each major release up to 5.18, as well as 5.20 and later.
- The `use strict;` and `use warnings;` lines set Perl to fussy.  You should always use them.
- The two assignments set up the values you specified in the question, except that it seems to be the 13th field from the right, rather than the 12th, that you want combined.  They're easily fungible if you need to.
- The `$, = ",";` lines sets the output field separator (`OFS` in Awk, and `$OFS` in Perl under `use English qw( -no_match_vars );`).  See [`perldoc English`](https://perldoc.perl.org/English.html) and [`perldoc perlvars`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvars.html).
- The `my($nflds) = scalar(@F);` line determines the number of fields.
- The `print` line is conditional on there being enough fields.
- It uses Perl's [array slices](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) to:

  - print fields `0..$lhs-1` as separate comma-separated fields
  - combine fields `$lhs..$nflds-$rhs-1` as a single space-separated field (by virtue of the string around the slice)
  - print fields `$nflds-$rhs..$nflds-1` as separate comma-separated fields

The output from that, given your input data, is:

```
1856292496,-1863203096,302,918468087151,808648712,405670043170066,919015026101,M,6,T,0,15,2c,Dear Customer  Your Request is under Process,03,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/,11/05/2017 10:00:00,0,03,,255,,333,ERecharge_RCOM,919015540301
1856292499,-1863203087,301,918081224379,808648711,405540046666191,919026240102,M,6,T,0,15,8d,Dear Business Partner your current Core balance is Rs.29.8 GSM balance is Rs.12892.14 MRCOM balance is Rs.1 and MRTL balance is Rs.1.Reliance,03,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/05/2017 10:00:00,11/,11/05/2017 10:00:00,0,01,,255,,333,BalQuery_RCOM,919835853611
```

Note that the leading space on one of the fields in the first line is preserved.

I didn't come up with that immediately.  I generated a more verbose solution like this, first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -l
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lhs = 13;
my $rhs = 13;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    my(@fields) = split /,/;
    my($nflds) = scalar(@fields);
    my(@output) = @fields;
    if ($nflds > $lhs + $rhs)
    {
        my(@combine) = @fields[$lhs .. $nflds-$rhs-1];
        my $composite = "@combine";
        @output = (@fields[0 .. $lhs-1], $composite, @fields[$nflds-$rhs .. $nflds-1]);
    }
    local $, = ",";
    print @output;
}
```

This produces the same output as the other script.  I had the scripts called `rs13.pl` (verbose) and `rs17.pl` (compact) and checked them like this (`data` contains your two lines of input data):

```
diff <(perl rs13.pl data) <(perl rs17.pl data)
```

There was no difference.

There are ways to make the compact solution more compact, but I'm not sure they help much.

---

Here is another version that uses the [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) and [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) functions instead of array slices.  In some ways, it is tidier than the other two, but it doesn't have the same protection against lines with too few fields in them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -anlF,
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lhs = 13;
my $rhs = 13;

$, = ",";     # Perl is obscure on occasion!
my($nflds) = scalar(@F);
splice(@F, $lhs, $nflds - $lhs - $rhs, join(' ', @F[$lhs .. $nflds-$rhs-1]));
print @F;
```

It produces the same result as the other two scripts.

---

Yes, you could write the code in Awk; it wouldn't be as compact as this.